# I need to get attribute of listbox selecteditem wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have that listbox: my bind is ProdutoGrupoViewModel, and list named as ListBoxGrupos

```xml
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="x:Name="ListBoxGrupos"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ProdutoGrupoViewModel}" 
         SelectionChanged="ListBoxGrupos_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ListViewGrupos">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descricao}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and when i get on my xaml.cs the property ListBoxGrupos.selectedItem, that returns for me an object

that object have some attributes

````
Obj.Descricao = "Pizzas"
Obj.GrupoCor = "FF8040"
Obj.GrupoID = 3 
Obj.Image = "..."
Obj.Position = "0" ```

(i tried to upload the image of that obj, but need reputation, so i tried to explain)

i want to know how can i get the attribute GrupoID.
````

Comment: By "attribute," you appear to mean "property." Are you talking about getting the value of the GrupoID property in the SelectionChanged event? Or are you trying to bind the selected item in the list box to some other control in the UI?

Comment: yes, property, sorry... i'm new with .net :p
So, i want to do the both one, get the value in the .cs and use to bind that value on the UI

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object to specified class

```
    Grupo gru = (Grupo)ListBoxGrupos.SelectedItem;

    gru.GrupoID = 3;
```